# Unknown column in where clause, it does exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    levelsloaded,
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM (
            (
                SELECT
                    id,
                    globalId,
                    date,
                    serverId,
                    playerId,
                    'playerjoins' AS origin 
                FROM
                    playerjoins
                WHERE
                    playerId = 2224
                    AND date <= levelsloaded.date 
                ORDER BY
                    date DESC
            ) UNION ALL (
                SELECT
                    id,
                    globalId,
                    date,
                    serverId,
                    playerId,
                    'playerleaves' AS origin 
                FROM
                    playerleaves
                WHERE
                    playerId = 2224
                    AND date <= levelsloaded.date 
                ORDER BY
                    date DESC
            )
            ORDER BY
                date DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) below2
    ) below
```

I can assure you that `levelsloaded.date` does exist.

Why do I keep getting the error: `SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'levelsloaded.date' in 'where clause'`.
I think that by the `SELECT * FROM levelsloaded` I already have selected everything from `levelsloaded`.

Comment: In the subquery you can't access the field from other joined table.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan How would I access it then, if that even makes sense?

Comment: Downvoter: Care to explain why the downvote? And close request.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this query?

Comment: @Nick.BA I'm trying to select for a specific player (specific `playerId`) all `levelsloaded` that are strictly between a join and a leave. That is the last event (combination of join/leave of that player) before the level loaded must be a join and the first event after the level loaded must be a leave.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan identified your problem and I don't think your query can be easily modified for a solution. IMO: You need to rewrite this query from "the ground up". You should load up a SQLFiddle with sample data and the results you want.  Then pose the question on how to solve your problem.  Its great you tried and have something to show but your query seems overly complicated. (That many ORDER BY's with only 1 LIMIT raises a red flag for me.)

Comment: What does your `levelsloaded` table look like?

Comment: @Nick.BA See this older question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225472/create-complex-query-from-three-simple-queries , for details. If you are trying to answer the full question, then that topic might be more appropiate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your join doesn't know the context in which to use `levelsloaded.date`.

**UPDATE**

I haven't tested this, but it should get you pretty close. Once we get the brute force solution, I think we can make this more efficient.

SELECT
        serverId,
        MAX(`date`) AS level_date
    FROM
        levelsloaded AS ll
    GROUP BY
        serverId

```
SELECT
    ll.*,
    pj.*,
    pl.*
FROM
    levelsloaded AS ll
JOIN (
    SELECT
        server_id,
        playerId,
        MAX(`date`) AS join_date
    FROM
        playerjoins
    WHERE
        playerId = 2246
    GROUP BY
        server_id,
        playerId
) AS pj ON pj.server_id = ll.server_id
JOIN (
    SELECT
        server_id,
        playerId,
        MAX(`date`) AS leave_date
    FROM
        playerleaves
    WHERE
        playerId = 2246
    GROUP BY
        server_id,
        playerId
) AS pl ON pl.server_id = ll.server_id
WHERE
    ll.date BETWEEN pj.join_date AND pl.leave_date;
```

Comment: I believe the `,` is performing a `CROSS JOIN` if I am not mistaken? So it is actually joining the table.

Comment: I don't see where `levelsloaded` is ever referenced, other than `levelsloaded.date`.

Comment: Edited my answer, just in case you weren't notified.

Comment: Can you please comment on how to you are getting to the solution? The query does not give the desired result yet and I'd like to understand it aswell :) Debugging the query as I speak now.

Comment: Debugged a bit and this approach will not work (yet): You are referring to `join_date` resp. `leave_date` as a constant variable, while it is not. It is only constant with respect to the current `ll.date` (in iterative view), as you want the last leave/join before the levelloaded and the first leave/join thereafter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41997/discussion-between-nick-ba-and-skiwi)

Answer (score 0):

Use back ticks around your column names. You have some column names that are also key words. The parser may be getting confused.

Comment: Having `date` backticked makes no difference. It would be a difference story if I'd call my column name `from` or `date()`.